# href link is not working in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

i'm trying to build a hyperlink from **index.blade.php** to **login.blade.php** by route. i defined a named route for this hyperlink but is not working.

here is my route code.

```
Route::get('/','HomeController@index');
Route::get('/login', 'HomeController@login_page')->name('login');
```

and here is my controller.

```
  public function login_page()
{
  return view('login');
}
```

and here is my view where i'm trying to set a hyperlink.

```
    <li><a href="{{route('login')}}">Log-in</a></li>
```

[image: show this message]

Comment: What about it isn't working?

Comment: I tend to use url, `{{ url('/login') }}`

Comment: login page isn't load.

Comment: Does it give an error? Does the URL look correct? "Not working" is the broadest issue out there, like going to the doctor and saying "Something hurts" but not pointing out if it's a finger, toe, or throat.

Comment: Also, I don't think you need `Route::get('/login'`,  it can just be `Route::get('login'`

Comment: replace `return view('login');` with `return "test login !!";` to see if it will hit the method !

Comment: are you running apache?

Comment: This looks like a server config issue, not a Laravel one. Show us how you're routing your traffic to index.php (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/installation#web-server-configuration)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set URL link in a menu link using Laravel blade template, use it {{url('dashboard')}}. Use this link in the  for example:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="{{url('dashboard')}}" class="active">Dashboard</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I think it will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your error message points to a server problem, not Laravel.

Make sure you'r [mod_rewrite for apache is installed and enabled.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5758551/2119863)

```
a2enmod rewrite
service apache2 restart
```

Then check your Laravel with:

In your console, run: `php artisan route:list` and see if you have a row similar to:

```
| Domain | Method   | URI        | Name          | Action                                            | Middleware                  |
+--------+----------+------------+---------------+---------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | login      | login         | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@login_page    | web,guest                   |
```

If you do not see the `login` part, try clearing route's cache with:

```
php artisan route:clear
```

Other than that, you are doing everything properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (Ubuntu 18.04), it does not seem to be Laravel but Apache.

Workaround: Install Xampp and use it as Localhost.